# jQuery preloader

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, хотел поинтересоваться есть ли возможность сделать preload при клике на кнопку что бы пользователя уведомить что происходит какое-то действие. У меня есть поиск на сайте но он реализован на backend не через ajax. Через ajax не сделал по той причине что это поиск не из БД а из данных которые парсятся на другом сайте. Что нужно сделать, надо что бы пользователь нажал на поиск и на время перезагрузки страницы появилась какая-то гифка, посоветовали сделать через событие onBeforeunload или если jQuery .unload() но не помогло, если это вообще возможно реализовать то подскажите как?

Comment: Вы подумайте, как можно показать прелоадер на перезагружающейся странице?

Comment: В принципе можно если страница перезагружается долго

Comment: да страница перезагружается иногда от 5 до 10сек

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После перезагрузки страницы loader исчезает.

```js
$("#search").click(function(){
  $(".loader").css({"opacity":"1"})
});
```

```css
.loader{
  opacity:0;
  transition:0.8s;
}
button#search {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    max-width: 362px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #FFC107;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:table
}
img {
   display:table;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<button id="search">Поиск</button>

<img class="loader" src="https://loading.io/spinners/typing/lg.-text-entering-comment-loader.gif">
```

Comment: это вмести с unload() использовать, картинку прописать строго или динамически в js добавить?

Comment: Нет, просто вставьте этот код, а картинку вставляйте как хотите